# No puedo enviar datos con ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Necesito que al hacer clic en un botón y que  me envíe muchos  datos a un archivo PHP. Los datos se encuentran en un formulario y también en una tabla que se abre dentro de un modal  pero surge un inconveniente al hacer clic en ese botón: se abre el modal y el botón no envía los datos que necesito. Muchas gracias
Adjunto el código :

```
  <div class="content-wrapper" >
  <div class="page-title">
  <div>


  ?>
  <h1><i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i> Gestion de Entregas </h1>

</div>

</div>
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="col-md-12" >
    <div class="card"  style="background-color: #F9F8F5; height: 210px">
      <div class="card-title-w-btn">
        <h3 class="title"><i class=""></i> Detalle de Producto</h3>

      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form  role="form" id="datos_pedido">


          <div class="col-md-4 " style="display: none;">
            <label class="control-label">IDarea:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="18" name="idarea" id="idarea" placeholder="Nombre"  value="<?php if (isset($id_area)) echo $id_area ?>"  readonly>
          </div>  



          <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <label class="control-label">Area destino</label>
            <input type="text" maxlength="25"class="form-control" name="dest_sal" id="dest_sal" placeholder="destino" value="" required >
          </div> 


          <div class="col-md-4 ">
            <label class="control-label">Receptor:</label>
            <input type="text" maxlength="35"class="form-control" name="receptor-sal" id="receptor-sal" placeholder="Receptor" value="" required>
          </div>  

          <div class="col-md-4">

            <label class="control-label">Fecha de Salida</label>
            <input style="max-height: 40px;" type="datetime-local"      class="form-control form-control-danger"  name= "fechaout" id="fechaout" title="Por favor ingrese fecha"   value="" autofocus required>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4"  style="display: none;">
            <div class="form-group-horizontal">
              <label class="control-label">Id_categoria</label>
              <input type="text" name="id_categoria" id="id_categoria" class="form-control" value= "">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class='col-md-4' style="display: none;">
            <label>Filtrar por categoría</label>
            <select class='form-control' name='categoria' id='categoria' >
              <option value="">Selecciona una categoría</option>
              <?php 

              $query_categoria=mysqli_query($conn,"select id_categoria, name from categorias where id_area = '$id_area'");
              while($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($query_categoria))   {

                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rw['id_categoria'];?>"><?php echo $rw['name']; $catera= $rw['id_categoria']; ?></option>


                <?php

              }
              ?>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2></h2>

            <button type="submit" name="add_tab" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AgregarPro" >Agregar Producto</button> <!--Este boton trae el modal con la tabla que esta descripto mas abajo-->

          </form>
        </div>
```

y a continuación coloco el código del MODAL

```
<div id="resultados1" class='col-md-12'></div><!-- Carga los datos ajax productos_pedido.php -->


<!-- Modal -->
<!-- Modal Busca Producto-->
<div class="modal fade" id="AgregarPro" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Buscar productos</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">                                              
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filtrar" placeholder="Buscar productos">
            </div>
            <a href="#" id="bus"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i> Buscar</a>
          </div>
          <div class="outer_div">                                          
            <?php
            require_once('data/conexion.php');
            $sql = "select * from productos where id_area = '$id_area'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            ?>       
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                <tbody class="buscar">    
                  <tr  class="warning">
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Marca</th>  
                    <th><span class="pull-right">Stock</span></th>
                    <th><span class="pull-right">Cantidad</span></th>
                    <th class='text-center' style="width: 36px;">Agregar</th>
                  </tr>
                  <?php
                  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $codigo=$row['id_producto'];
                    $producto=$row['name'];
                    $marca=$row['marca'];
                    $stock=$row['stock_actual'];
                    $cantidad=$row['precio_unidad'];                                            
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $codigo; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $producto; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $marca; ?></td>
                      <td class='col-xs-1'>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="cantidad_<?php echo $codigo ?>" value="<?php echo $stock ?>">
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class='col-xs-2'>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name= "cants" id="cants" style="text-align:right" value="">
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td class='text-center'>
                        <a class='btn btn-info'href="#" onclick="agregar(<?php echo $codigo ?>)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a> **<!--Este boton es el que envia los datos de la tabla en  el modal -->**
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php    
                  }               
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div><!-- Datos ajax Final -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>                  
        </div>
```

Este es el script que envía los datos pero no se como agregar mas variables, por ejemplo los datos del form y otros datos de la tabla.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function agregar(id){  
        var cant = document.getElementById('cantidad_'+id).value;
        var cants = document.getElementById('cants').value;

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "ajax/agregar_pedido.php",
          data:  "codigo="+id+"&canti="+cant+"&cants="+cants,
          success: function (datos){
            $("#resultados1").html(datos);

          }                                
        });
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Tu archivo `agregar_pedido.php` esta dentro de una carpeta llamada ajax?

Comment: si...esta en una carpeta llamada ajax ...pero si envia datos...el problema es que no puedo enviar varios datos...el ejemplo lo copie de una ayuda que me pasaron

Comment: la variable cants pertenece a un input que esta en la tabla que a su vez esta en el Modal y no envia nada no se como deberia declararla en el script

Comment: Logre que en el botón del modal que hace referencia a la funcion agregar me tome los datos pero me queda muy extenso especificar 5 "id" de lo inputs en él

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues eh visto  varios errores en tu codigo sobre todo en el apartado que dice data dentro de tu llamada ajax

```
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AdminView.aspx/getInforRecords",
                data: '{idUpload:"' + idExcel + '",tipoFile:"' + tipoFile + '"}',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
//Aqui van tus acciones si es que se hace bien la llamada ajax
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(error)
                }
            });
```

Tu deberías de cambiar el formato de tu linea data en ajax como la tienes a la siguiente forma

```
data: '{idUpload:"' + idExcel + '",tipoFile:"' + tipoFile + '"}',
```

No se usan signos "=" ni tampoco es necesario un símbolo "&" como prefijo de las variables y al archivo a donde van ir también debe de tener las mismas variables con el mismo nombre para que las pueda encontrar y procesar.

Comment: Ok voy entendiendo , desde ya gracias... y  los id de los inputs que contienen los valores los debo mencionar en el botón que hace refencia a la funcion como explique anteriormente?

Comment: @Julio si debes mencionar los id's porque es la forma en que accederas a los valores para despues enviarlos

Comment: Muchas Gracias David ...preguntaba porque mencionar los id en el boton queda muy extenso.....pero bueno si no hay otra forma...

Comment: @Julio si no hay problema, hay otra forma que conozco pero igual involucra a los id's